# Simplify code by distributing []

Tags: list, haskell, monads

I have the following function

```
type Assignment = [(Ref, Val)]

predi2 :: [(Val,Val)] -> Ref -> Ref -> (Maybe Assignment -> [Maybe Assignment])
predi2 f k1 k2 = \ma -> case ma of
    Nothing -> [Nothing]
    Just a -> case lookup k1 a of
        Nothing -> [Nothing]
        Just e1 -> case lookup k2 a of
            Nothing -> [Nothing]
            Just e2 -> if elem (e1, e2) f
                then [Just a]
                else []
```

Given all the instances of Maybe, I thought I could simplify it to something more simple inside the Maybe monad:

```
predi2 :: [(Val,Val)] -> Ref -> Ref -> (Maybe Assignment -> [Maybe Assignment])
predi2 f k1 k2 = [\ma -> do
    a <- ma
    e1 <- lookup k1 a
    e2 <- lookup k2 a
    if elem (e1, e2) f then (return a) else ???]
```

But my problem is the final else, where I need to return nothing.

That is my question: Is it possible to return nothing in a way such that [f a] = []?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it's not.

I would write your `predi2` function more like this:

```
predi2 f k1 k2 ma = fromMaybe [Nothing] $ do
    a <- ma
    e1 <- lookup k1 a
    e2 <- lookup k2 a
    if elem (e1, e2) f then return [Just a] else return []
```

i.e.

- post-process the monadic computation, using `fromMaybe`
- have the list inside the monadic computation, instead of outside it
- have the False branch of the if statement count as successful (by the standards of the monadic computation)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's possible, if I understand the question correctly.

What strikes me is that you're trying to track two different kinds of failure, the empty list indicates that the final `elem` lookup failed. The `Maybe` indicates that either (1) the original `Maybe Assignment` was `Nothing` or (2) either `lookup` failed. We can be more explicit about this. The return type ought to be something like

```
data FailureType = Existence | SeenInF
Either FailureType Assignment
```

Then we'll just translate the `Maybe` type failures into `Either`s using the [errors](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors) module.

```
import Control.Error
predi2 :: [(Val, Val)] -> Ref -> Ref -> Maybe Assignment -> Either FailureType Assignment
predi2 f k1 k2 ma = do a  <- note Existence ma
                       e1 <- note Existence $ lookup k1 a
                       e2 <- note Existence $ lookup k2 a
                       note SeenInF $ guard $ (e1, e2) `elem` f
                       return a
```

This solution is a little strange since it involves translating between the two failure monads, `Maybe` and `Either`, but [`note`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/errors/latest/doc/html/Control-Error-Util.html#v%3anote) is an incredibly useful function for this purpose.